# Solution for "Subquery returns more than 1 row"

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to substitute my join SQL code to a different code without any of JOIN statements for faster data retrieval. However, i'm getting the error below.

```
#1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row
```

What i would like to do, get all rows from one table 'tbl_my_itemlist' and JOIN to other more tables, tbl_register  and tbl_register without using JOIN statements.

The Code using JOIN statement (works fine).

```
SELECT
    tbl_screenshots.screenshot_image_url,
    mit.my_itemlist_id,
    mit.item_name,
    mit.item_initial_cost,
    mit.item_offer_cost,
    mit.offer_date_from,
    mit.offer_date_to
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        my_itemlist_id
    FROM
        tbl_my_itemlist
    WHERE
        offer_date_from >='2020-10-20' AND offer_date_to <= '2020-10-30'  AND 

item_deleted_status = 'active'
) mlist
JOIN tbl_my_itemlist mit ON
    mit.my_itemlist_id = mlist.my_itemlist_id
RIGHT JOIN tbl_screenshots ON mit.my_itemlist_id = 

tbl_screenshots.my_itemlist_id
RIGHT JOIN tbl_register ON tbl_register.register_id = mit.register_id
GROUP BY
    mit.my_itemlist_id
     ORDER BY mit.offer_date_to ASC LIMIT 2
```

The code i'm substituting the JOIN statement code with.

```
SELECT
    mit.my_itemlist_id,
    mit.item_name,
    mit.item_initial_cost,
    mit.item_offer_cost,
    mit.offer_date_from,
    mit.offer_date_to,
    (
    SELECT
        reg.business_name
    FROM
        tbl_register reg
    WHERE
        reg.register_id = mit.register_id
) reg_sql,
(
    SELECT
        sshots.screenshot_image_url
    FROM
        tbl_screenshots sshots
    WHERE
        sshots.my_itemlist_id = mit.my_itemlist_id
) sshots_sq
FROM
    tbl_my_itemlist mit
WHERE
    mit.offer_date_from >= '2020-10-20' AND mit.offer_date_to <= '2020-10-30' AND mit.item_deleted_status = 'active'
GROUP BY
    mit.my_itemlist_id
ORDER BY
    mit.offer_date_to ASC
LIMIT 2
```

I'm trying to build an SQL query that can retrieve data from million records within very short period of time as compared to using the JOIN statement.

Comment: Which row do you want when there is more than one row?  If you don't care, just add `limit 1` to the subquery.

Comment: for example, i have a product which you can add upto 10 screenshots. I would like to retrieve all products and their JOINED screenshots.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff , thankyou for the clue

Comment: . . If you want the values in separate rows you need to use `join`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Okey i understand. And how can i improve My JOIN statement to prevent looping across all screenshots rows and register rows? JOIN only the required rows

Comment: How are the indexes on tbl_register , tbl_my_itemlist and tbl_screenshots looking like.. I will create indexes 1. tbl_register(my_itemlist_id ,my_itemlist_id, offer_date_to)  2. on the join keys for the remaining table. Also will be helpful to share the explain plan and the indexes

Comment: Move the subquery from the SELECT list, do a LEFT JOIN instad.

Comment: Note that nobody ever uses RIGHT JOIN.

Comment: For further help, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Thankyou for all those comments. After thorough research, i have realized this issue of fast retrieval can be only be solved by creating indexes. I am new to indexes but i will try my level best to understand them.